# Compute matrix and data frame

Tags: r

I´m beginner in `R` and need some help with the following sequence code:

```
set.seed(2010)
A <- matrix(sample(18),nrow=6)
```

How can I get all the rows but with only odd columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `A[,c(TRUE,FALSE)]`:

```
A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    6   16    2
#[2,]    9    1    3
#[3,]    8    5   17
#[4,]    4   11   18
#[5,]   12   14   10
#[6,]   13    7   15

A[,c(T,F)]               # the first and third columns are picked up due to cycling
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    6    2
#[2,]    9    3
#[3,]    8   17
#[4,]    4   18
#[5,]   12   10
#[6,]   13   15
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to select the rows directly using `seq`:

```
A[, seq(1,ncol(A), by = 2)]

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    6    2
#[2,]    9    3
#[3,]    8   17
#[4,]    4   18
#[5,]   12   10
#[6,]   13   15
```